# Find value of a randomly chosen key from dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, random

I have a .py dictionary which I want to use in another file. I want to randomly choose a key

```
w_keys = dictionary.dic.keys()

def inf():
   return random.choice(list(w_keys))

x = inf()
```

and then I need to find the value of the chosen key,

```
value = dictionary.dic.values()
return dictionary.dic[x] == value
```

but I am not sure how to do so and my attempts (unsurprisingly) don't work?

Comment: What attempts? I don't see any here.

Comment: @usr2564301  I meant the code starting with ''value =''

Comment: Try `return dictionary.dic.get(x, None)`

Comment: @GarbageCollector that solved it! Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

```
import random

dict = {'A': 'a', 'B': 'b'}

def inf(dict):
   return random.choice(list(dict.keys()))

x = dict[inf(dict)]
```